# Error in Preparing Msword document in salesforce visualforce/apex page

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, ms-word

I am preparing Msword(Proposal) document in salesforce visualforce page.There is a small box in a header and footer level and special character in the content. I want to remove the  small box and replace the [image]special character with actual characters. Kindly help me.

See the below code and attached error image

```html
 <apex:page sidebar="false" contentType="application/msword#{!filename}.doc" cache="true" controller="GenerateDoccumentController" lightningStylesheets="true">
    
    <html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns='https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/SPSD-html401-20180327/'> 
    
        <head>
            <style>
                  
                <!-- *************-->
                p.MsoHeader, li.MsoHeader, div.MsoHeader{
                    margin:0in;
                    margin-top:.0001pt;
                    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
                    tab-stops:center 3.0in right 6.0in;
                }
                p.MsoFooter, li.MsoFooter, div.MsoFooter{
                    margin:0in;
                    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
                    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
                tab-stops:center 3.0in right 6.0in;
                }
                @page Section1{
                    size:8.5in 11.0in; 
                    margin:0.5in 0.5in 0.5in 0.5in;
                    mso-header-margin:0.5in;
                    mso-header:h1;
                    mso-footer:f1; 
                    mso-footer-margin:0.5in;
                    mso-paper-source:0;
                }
                div.Section1{
                    page:Section1;
                }
                /*Below is the style to prevent the repetition of header and Footer.. Cheers!!!*/
                table#hrdftrtbl{
                    margin:0in 0in 0in 9in;
                }       
            </style>
        </head>

        <body>
            <!-- Content -->
            <div class="Section1"><!--Section1 div starts-->
                <center>
              <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!proposalHead}">
              <p><b><u>Proposal</u></b></p>
              </apex:outputPanel>
              
              <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!tradeHead}">
              <p><b><u>Trade Recap</u></b></p>
              </apex:outputPanel>
              
              </center>
              
              <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!proposalText}">
              <p>Attn:    {!gdw.contactRoleName} </p>
              <p> Ref.:   {!gdw.year} Proposal for up to {!gdw.totalOppQty} metric tons of {!gdw.prodGroup} Zinc. </p>
              <p> Please find below our proposal for the supply of {!gdw.prodGroup} Zinc during Calendar year {!gdw.year} </p>
              </apex:outputPanel>
              
              <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!tradeText}">
             <!-- <p>Pursuant to the Master Sale and Purchase Agreement (the "Master Agreement") reference number {!gdw.contractRef}, between {!gdw.seller} and {!gdw.buyer}, the parties agree upon the following sale and purchase on {!gdw.closeDt}</p>
               <p>To the extent not inconsistent with this Trade Recap but not defined herein shall have the meanings given them in the Master Agreement.</p>-->
                  {!gdw.tradeInitialPara}
               </apex:outputPanel>
               
               <table style="width:100%" border="1">
              
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Contract Ref:</td>
                <td>{!gdw.contractRef}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Seller:</td>
                <td>{!gdw.seller}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Buyer:</td>
                <td>{!gdw.buyer}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Metal:</td>
                <td><apex:outputtext value="{!gdw.metal}" escape="false"/></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>Quantity:</td>
                <td>{!gdw.quantity}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>Quality and Brand:</td>
                <td><apex:outputtext value="{!gdw.quantityAndBrand}" escape="false"/></td>
              </tr>
              
              <tr>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>Delivery Period:</td>
                <td>{!gdw.deliveryPeriod}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>Delivery:</td>
                <td>{!gdw.deliveryLocation}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>Origin:</td>
                <td>{!gdw.origin}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>Price:</td>
                  <td>  {!a} <br/> <apex:outputtext value="{!gdw.price}" escape="false"/> <br/> <apex:outputtext value="{!b}" escape="false"/> <br/>{!c} </td>
                
              </tr>
              
              
              <tr>
                <td>11</td>
                <td>Quotational Period:</td>
                <td>{!gdw.quotationalPeriod}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>Payment:</td>
                <td>{!gdw.payment}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>13</td>
                <td>Weights:</td>
                <td>{!gdw.weights}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>14</td>
                <td>Law/Jurisdiction:</td>
                <td>{!gdw.law_Jurisdiction}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>General Terms and Condition:</td>
                <td>{!gdw.terms_Condition}</td>
              </tr>
               <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!framerow}">
              <tr>
                <td>{!framelinenumber}</td>
                <td>Frame details:</td>
                <td>{!gdw.FrameDet}</td>
              </tr>
              </apex:outputPanel>
              <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!tableRow}">
              <tr>
                <td>{!validitylinenumber}</td>
                <td>Validity:</td>
                <td>{!gdw.closeDt}</td>
              </tr>
              </apex:outputPanel>
              
            </table>
              
                <!--Header and Footer Starts-->
                <table id='hrdftrtbl' ><!--border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'-->
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <!--Header-->
                            <div style='mso-element:header' id="h1" >
                               <p class="MsoHeader">
                                    <center>
                                      <apex:image url="{!$Label.URL}id={!$Label.DocumentId}&oid={!$Label.OrganizationId}&lastMod={!$Label.LastModified}" width="150" height="75"/><br/>
                                      
                                       <b>{!gdw.seller}</b>
                                      </center>
                                      <br/>
                                    
                                </p>
                             
                            </div>
                            <!-- <div style='mso-element:header' id="h1">
                                 <p class="MyHead">Header Text</p></div>-->
                           
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <!--Footer-->
                            <div style='mso-element:footer' id="f1">
                                <p class="MsoFooter">
                                    <center>
                                        <b>{!gdw.seller}</b> <br/>
                                        {!gdw.Address1} <br/>
                                        {!gdw.Address2} <br/><br/>
                                    </center>
                                    
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </body>    
    </html>  
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is a stray character or characters. I don't see any special characters (Unicode or control) in your markup that your font is struggling with, so I'm leaning towards malformed markup. A few things to try.

1. Remove the Lightning Style Sheets from your `apex:page` (`lightningStylesheets="false"`). At best they do nothing, at worst they interfere with formatting.
2. Include `showHeader="false"` in `apex:page`. I doubt it's an issue, but it doesn't hurt to be explicit.
3. Remove the HTML comments from your CSS (`<!-- *************-->`). CSS comments are in the format `/* comment */`.

Additionally, I know it can be counter-intuitive to *not* use Visualforce tags in a Visualforce page, but the output they generate may be an issue. If you can, I would consider using *only* valid HTML tags in your markup to eliminate potential issues. If you keep any of the VF tags, it would be [`apex:outputPanel`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputPanel.htm) because those either generate markup or they don't, but I would use `layout="none"` on them so they aren't generating extra `<span>` tags around your markup (it should be fine without them).

You can take your document and open it up in an IDE to get a glimpse of the underlying XML, but with documents such as these the issue would be difficult to find.